# wp_redirect in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am developing a wordpress plugin where I want to authenticate and redirect user to another page. But it's showing the following error:

```
"WARNING: CANNOT MODIFY HEADER INFORMATION - HEADERS ALREADY SENT BY (OUTPUT STARTED AT D:\WAMP\WWW\ABC_WEEKLY_REPORT\WP-INCLUDES\POST-TEMPLATE.PHP:1187)".
```

I don't know how to make the redirection work.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['login']))

{
    if (isset($_POST['awr_username']))
    {
        $username=$_POST['awr_username'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['awr_password']))
    {
        $pass=$_POST['awr_password'];

    }

    global $wpdb;

        function awr_check_user($username,$pass) {
                $user=wp_authenticate( $username, $pass );
                if (is_wp_error($user))
                {
                    $error=$user->get_error_message();
                    echo $error;

                }
                else
                {
                    wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit;
                }

            }   
        add_action('awr_user_auth', 'awr_check_user',1,2);
        do_action('awr_user_auth',$username,$pass);

}

?>
```

Comment: Are the spaces before your opening `<?php` in the actual source? If so, there's your output.

Comment: no. there isn't any spaces before opening <?php